# Rails 3: Controller returns class method nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, mongoid

So I got this class method:

```
  def self.auth(id, key_code_in)
    post = Post.where(:id => id).first   
    if post.key_code == key_code_in
      post
    else
      nil
    end   
  end
```

It loves the console:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > authtest = Post.auth('5032f3254ff9fcf10100001b', 42745590875)
=> #<Post _id: 5032f3254ff9fcf10100001b, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-08...
```

But hates the controller:

```
  #GET posts/:id/remove_form
  def remove_form
  end

  #POST posts/:id
  def code
    @id = params[:id]
    @key = params[:destroy_code]    
    @post = Post.auth(@id, @key)

    render :text => params[@post].inspect
  end
```

Gets me nil, every time. I made sure the params are being passed from the view form_tag and they are. So ruling that out... what on earth is going on? Any help would be greatly appreciated by a plethora of up votes.

Comment: Btw `auth` in its current form would fail with exception `NoMethodError: undefined method `key_code' for nil:NilClass` if supplied `id` is not present in db. Enhancing `if` this way would help: `if post && post.key_code == key_code_in`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it !

Why are you accessing `params[@post]` ? The result of this method should simply be in `@post`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the parameter a String (your comparison is expecting an Integer).

You can convert it with the to_i method.

Comment: Yes sir, my key variable is an integer. Thank you for your quick reply! I tried strapping the .to_i on the back of key_code_in.to_i and I can put '' around the code in console now, but in the controller it is still returning nil. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
If your using the id properly.

def code
    @id = params[:id].to_i
    @key = params[:destroy_code]
    @post = Post.auth(@id, @key)

```
render :text => @post.inspect
```

end